# how to run custom code after every $model->save() function in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, logging, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to execute my custom code after or before every `$model->save()` in `Yii2`.

I want to perform this globally like using `components`, etc.

I want to create a user activity log to store how many times a user insert or update any rows in database table, so for this I want to run some code when ever data inserted or update in tables.

Any help or suggestion will appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As @patryk mentioned `ActiveRecord` has [beforeSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail) and [afterSave](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail) methods.

I use something like the following to store a created date for new records (and updated date when existing records are updated). The code in the example is, of course, trivial but it allows you to use any arbitrary code you need, see the layout and how to split code for 'new' records and existing.

This overridden method can be added to any model class which extends `ActiveRecord` to allow the parent `beforeSave` to be called correctly also.

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($insert) {
        // This is a new instance of modelClass, run your 'insert' code here.
        $this->created_date = time();
    }
    // Anything else will be run any time a model is saved.
    $this->updated_date = time();

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

edited to add:
if the code to be run is the same for each model you could create a trait and use the trait in each model to allow you to change the behaviour in one place. Or create a custom `ActiveRecord` class to override the `beforeSave` method for each subclass.

Comment: i want to use it as component or as global function . i have almost 80 models files and it difficult for me to edit every file and write this code there.

Comment: @FahadAli; in that case, perhaps a trait or custom superclass?

Comment: can you please suggest me something

Answer (score 1):

Create new class(MyActiveRecord) which extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord

Use extends  MyActiveRecord to all your project models

Ex:

```
class MyActiveRecord extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{ 

 public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    //This will called after every model saved

  return parent::beforeSave($insert,$changedAttributes);
 }




}
```

In your project other models

```
class Customer extends app\models\MyActiveRecord
{ 



}
```

Comment: i want to use it as component or as global function . i have almost 80 models files and it difficult for me to edit every file and write this code there.

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 `ActiveRecord` class has `beforeSave` and `afterSave` methods. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L926

But maybe it would be better to do such operation on database triggers?